# How to convert string value to object in Javascript with command similar to eval in Python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, typescript

In Python `stringValue` was given as a string variable:

```
stringValue = '{"DATA":{"VERSION":1.1, "STATE":True, "STATUS":"ONLINE"}}'
```

I can go ahead and "convert" or "cast" it as Python dictionary using `eval` built in function:

```
result = eval(stringValue)
```

Is there a way to do the same in javascript if we would be given `var stringValue` as:

```
var stringValue = '{"DATA":{"VERSION":1.1, "STATE":true, "STATUS":"ONLINE"}}'
```

Comment: you changed the string format, so now you CAN use JSON.parse as that string is now JSON - as to where has JSON been mentioned ... well, now that you edited the question, the string IS JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use eval

With one caveat ... you'll need to add `(` and `)` to the string

```js
// this is the ORIGINAL value of the string in the question!!!
var stringValue = "{'DATA':{'VERSION':1.1, 'STATE':true, 'STATUS':'ONLINE'}}";
var result = eval(`(${stringValue})`);
console.log(result)
```

Now that code in the question was changed by you after I posted the original answer ...  i.e. swapped `'` and `"` - now you CAN use `JSON.parse` as a comment suggested

```js
var stringValue = '{"DATA":{"VERSION":1.1, "STATE":true, "STATUS":"ONLINE"}}';
var result = JSON.parse(stringValue);
console.log(result);
```